# Protege ontop reasoner Initialization error

Tags: protege, protege4

I am following the  Protege on tutorials, am I using ONTOP version 5.1.0, but whenever I start the reasonser I get this error.

I have added the MySQL jdbc driver to the preferences tab but I still getting the error.

what should I do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The error you are getting is missing from the question, please add a text or screenshot description.